# how do you show functional dependency in an er diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram, functional-dependencies

how do you show functional dependency in an er diagram? My assignment says "All functional dependencies should be shown, even if all or some tables are already normalized".

Can someone help me with what this means?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is meant by a "functional dependency", preferably with some examples?

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure but I'm guessing something like this:
I have an entity called ALBUM, one called SONG and one called ALBUM_SONG. Album song is functionally dependent on ALBUM and SONG because it needs a songID and an albumID to exist, which are foreign keys from their two respective tables. I THINK that is what is meant by functional dependencies in this instance - but I'm not sure how to show them.

Comment: That sounds more like a foreign key dependency. It may be a good idea to ask the giver of the assignment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Learn what a "functional dependency" (FD) is. Read a textbook or even Wikipedia. (Do not take information modeling advice from someone who doesn't know what a FD is.) You cannot actually determine a table's "candidate keys" (CKs) without knowing the FDs. (Ie its unique column sets that don't contain smaller unique column sets.) One CK can be picked as "primary key" (PK).

A FD is a kind of condition/constraint on a table/relation value or on a base table/relation (ie table/relation variable) that only holds such constrained table values. If a FD is present then typically a bunch of other related "implied" ones are too. So we usually find a "canonical cover" which is a set of FDs that imply all the original ones and the ones they imply but which cannot be made smaller. It captures all the relevant information concisely. If someone asks for the FDs of a table then they generally mean they want a canonical cover.

A FD is written as a source/determining column/attribute set followed by a rightward arrow followed by a target/determined attribute set. An ER diagram does not express FDs. (Certain FDs are implied by CKs though.) Use your ER diagramming tool's text annotations. (Naturally, ask the person requesting the FDs what they want.)

Normalization replaces a table/relation by smaller component tables/relations that natural join back to it. In general some of those FDs are no longer associated with any component. In practice given some tables/relations that arose from normalization there will be FDs that held in original tables that are relevant and hold in natural joins of those components even though they do not hold in any component. It is reasonable to document those. But then, there are lots of relevant constraints that ER diagrams cannot express, and some particular ones they can.